# What's the difference between `_type` and `type` in elasticsearch from filebeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

What's the difference between `_type` and `type` in elasticsearch from filebeat?

Looking the data from the query:
[image]

Looks like, the `_type` is the doc type from index, and `type` is just a field of my source data. If it is, why does filebeat set `document_type` to be `type` instead of `_type`?

Comment: i donot your confusion. json->_source->type is your custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is 5.5.0, right?

This is a preparation for Elasticsearch 6.0, which will only use a single `_type` per index called `doc` (though this can be changed through a configuration flag); Elasticsearch 7.0 will completely remove `_type`. So the value has been moved to the custom `type` field.

The pull request for this change is https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/3757, which also links to the relevant Elasticsearch issue.

Comment: Yes. That's the answer I am looking for. Thanks.